# Как сверстать разделенный фон?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно сверстать такой вот разделенный фон?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фактура естественно не нужна. Просто два однотонных цвета с таким вот волнистым переходом. Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем его верстать? Почему бы не взять и поставить эту самую картинку на фон?

Comment: Кто и зачем исключил? В чём смысл?

Comment: Можете заморочиться с градиентом и clip-path, но картинкой в svg всё же лучше

Comment: @Кузьма Поставил вам плюсик, как новому участнику. Вопрос закрыл, как дубликат, пройдите по ссылке, там много ответов на точно такой же вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Но если подумать то можно разделить первую часть : `path` а вторая часть это фон  для rect в виде [`pattern'а`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/pattern)

и в итоге это выглядит так:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <defs>
     <pattern id="pattern"  width="100%" height="100%">
      <image xlink:href="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/point_gray_texture_55269_2560x1080.jpg"              x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
    </pattern>   
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
  <path d="M0,0 Q320,80 500,250 Q580,350 1000,500 L0,500z" fill="#121212"/>
</svg>
```

Дальше это надо доработать вместо 100%  высоты svg'шку поставить куда то и растянуть ..и тогда будет нужный результат ..но чисто из снимка экрана я пока это вижу так